# Parsing json array with no arrayobject name in android

Tags: android, json

I want to parse the following data, everything is done but i'm confused at this last stage:

```
["ABC","DEF","GHI"]
```

How can I parse this type of json data?

Comment: sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(data); // assuming your json array is store in data
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    String str = arr.getString(i); // will return one string at a time
}
```

Comment: thanks, i m retrieving data from server, so how to create this  JSONArray object.. JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr); from this.

Comment: Please post the code where you are getting this json

Comment: jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("");

JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(data);

Comment: `data` is the variable where `["ABC","DEF","GHI"]` is stored. try this.

Comment: I have JSONObject, see this  JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(url); ok? Now how to create JSONArray object?